# How can I kill anaconda in windows?

Tags: anaconda

There is an instance of anaconda navigator running on my windows 10 machine. I tried to quit but it becomes unreachable (the cursor is a circle). 
I can not close it. 
I can not kill it with the right click
I can not kill it with the Task manager because the "access is not allowed"

There is no way to kill the program (from all that know or could find in the internet)

What can I do to terminate the anaconda navigator?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Task Manager as administrator, and then trying to kill the task? Explained in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/199148/run-task-manager-as-another-user-administrator

Comment: thanks. I will try. Unfortunately I just found out that I forgot the administrator password